# Cassandra - Difference between CLI and CQL

Tags: .net, nosql, cassandra, bigdata

I am new to Cassandra and learning the things. I have seen there are several Cassandra Client APIs, such as `Cassandra CLI` , `CQL` etc. I need to know what exactly the difference between `CLI` and `CQL` ? Which one shall be better to use ? Also, what are the client APIs available to query Cassandra using .NET ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: CLI is Command Line Interface to explore data and schema of cassandra cluster [Ex: redis-cli]. CQL is Cassandra Query Language [like SQL for RDBMS] A way to query the data through various high end clients [like java - hector, php - phpcassa, python - pycassa]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CQL](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/index) - a SQL (Structured Query Language)-like language for querying Cassandra. Easy way of using cql is to try out the `cqlsh` tool that ships with Cassandra.
[CLI](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli) - A command-line application that can be used to query Cassandra.

There are a number of popular High level C# Cassandra client APIs most of which support CQL.

- [Aquiles](http://aquiles.codeplex.com/) - Includes examples but requires a bit of configuration (explained in their [wiki](http://aquiles.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Aquiles.Configuration&referringTitle=Home))
- [Hector Sharp](https://github.com/mattvv/hectorsharp) - Lacks documentation, but thanks to their tests you can work out what to do, and I found [this blog](http://www.sinbadsoft.com/blog/cassandra-meets-hectorsharp/) with some useful info.
- [Fluent Cassandra](https://github.com/managedfusion/fluentcassandra) - Requires some configuration but getting started is explained very well in [their blog](http://coderjournal.com/2010/06/your-first-fluent-cassandra-application/).

**Note** You could always use the Thrift API, but I'd advise against it as its a low level implementation and requires lots of code to get anything done.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible high-level client for .NET is cassandra-sharp: https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp

I haven't actually used cassandra-sharp.
I was able to poke around in Fluent Cassandra, though, with out much effort (though with some pre-existing Cassandra knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

There is a new library for accessing Cassandra in .NET: https://github.com/reuzel/CqlSharp CqlSharp (like CassandraSharp) implements the new Cassandra binary protocol. The CqlSharp API is very much ADO like, and implemented async from the ground up. The wiki has examples on how to use it.